# How do I call a different REST API within a express route?

Tags: node.js, api, express, post

I have an express.js REST API that I have created with a variety of routes. I'd like to create a route to call another REST API and then return the result. Ideally, it should look something like the following:

```
router.post('/CreateTicket', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
   //make a call to another rest api and then res.send the result
}
```

The REST API route that I am calling is a POST request and will take in a JSON body with the information for the ticket. It then will return a JSON response containing the ticket information and ticket link.

Essentially, I just want to pass req.body as the body of the API call and then res.send() the response of the API call. I was trying to figure out some way to use fetch or requests, but was just getting confused.

Thank you so much for any help that anyone can offer!

Comment: Would you like to call any third-party lib or your own route?

Comment: I'd like users of my API to just call my route, but then all that route does is pass in the body from the call to the other API and then return that API's response. I can use third-party libraries as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) if you want to call the third-party API. The simple way of doing is to create an options(config) pass it to the axios object.

```
npm i axios --save
```

Axios config

```
  const options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://URL',
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
       firstName: 'Fred',
       lastName: 'Flintstone'
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await axios(options);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
  }
```

In your route file:

```
const axios = require('axios');


const getData = async (body) => {
      const options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://URL',
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
      body
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await axios(options);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
  }
}

router.post('/CreateTicket', cors(corsOptions), async function(req, res, next) {
   //make a call to another rest api and then res.send the result
  try {
    const response = await getData(req.body);
   res.send(response);
  } catch (e) {
    //wrap your error object and send it
  }
   
}
```

Note: if you want to pass the data to your own created route you can use `res.redirect` and it will send the response back. You can check the `axios` details in the link above.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you so much! One quick question: where would the config go? In the same file as the routes?

Comment: Yes or you can create a helper function in different file to reuse it. It will be based on your usage. If you want to use at one place only, you can put it in the same file.

Comment: One last quick question: the line "const response = await getData(req.body)" seems to cause an error because the router.post is not an asynchronous function. However, since get Data is an asynchronous function, how else should we be waiting for the response?

Comment: Make call the async function, it won't generate any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use something like axios or [http](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) (code originates from link):

```js
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'example.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'GET'
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    return d
  })
}
```