# How to call a POST api inside a Post api in node.js, express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

I am trying to make a fetch in react.js using backend node.js api url which then further makes a post api call within the server to another route using another url.

How am i supposed to do that?
Take a look at the code below:

From the frontend "/confirm" api will be called using fetch.

```
app.post("/save-info",(req,res)=>{
   //Does some more stuff and returns a 
   response to the confirm api.

}

app.post("/confirm", (req,res)=>{
   //Does some stuff

   //Makes another call inside this api 
   to the "/save-info" route

}
```

**Updated Query**

Guys, please take a look at the code below

```
async function signUp(info) {
    const {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        address,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        password,
        city,
        postal_code,
    } = info;

    console.log("only info: ", phoneNumber);

    const queryInsertNewUser = `INSERT INTO public."Users"(
        "First_Name", "Email", "Mobile", "Address", "User_Type", "Last_Name", "password", "city","postal_code")
        VALUES ('${firstName}', '${email}', '${phoneNumber}', '${address}', 'Customer', '${lastName}', '${password}','${city}','${postal_code}')
        RETURNING user_id;`;

    // return { email: "kalo", id: "23" };

    client.query(queryInsertNewUser, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            if (result.rowCount == 1) {
                console.log("User registered.");
                return {
                    status: "Success",
                    msg: "User Registered Successfully",
                    user_id: result.rows[0].user_id,
                };
            } else {
                console.log("Not Registered.");
                return {
                    status: "Error",
                    msg: "Could not register user. Call Developer.",
                };
            }
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}


app.post("/signup", async(req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const data = await signUp(req.body);
    console.log(data);
});
```

data is printing undefined. Still it does not work

Comment: learn to use `next()`, pull out both them functions then do `app.post("/confirm", [confirm, saveInfo]`, next or throw error from confirm

Comment: rtm: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: This seems to be duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69657782/how-do-i-call-a-different-rest-api-within-a-express-route

Comment: Try this, if this would work for data returning undefined https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075302/6752055

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call your route again. Just create an function and call it.

```js
const saveInfo = ()=>{
  // do wathever you want here
  return "some stuff done"
}

app.post("/save-info",(req,res)=>{
   // you probabbly don't need this route.

}

app.post("/confirm", (req,res)=>{
   //Does some stuff

   const data = saveInfo()
   return res.send({success:true, done})

}
```

Comment: Tried your way but saveInfo function is returning undefined. 
Please Note that, inside saveInfo function I am trying to insert values in the postgresql DB which returns the id of the inserted field.

Comment: @HasinSadique In your case, calling a function is the right way as mentioned in this answer. Show through your code whatever error you are facing after implementing this aforementioned approach.

Comment: @DaniyalMalik Please take a look at the code below updated query.

Comment: @HasinSadique You are using callback to handle the result from `client.query`, use `await` instead. I will update my answer as well.

Comment: @HasinSadique In short, just replace your current `client.query` call with `const res = await client.query(queryInsertNewUser);`